# Temporary removal of HTML from string for Google Translate API to reduce cost

Tags: php, api, html-parsing, translation, google-translate

I have to translate some details using a Google API which we're paying for. The details contain HTML, and Google charges for each character.  I don't want to send the complete content, but only the English text instead, with the HTML removed. I can remove HTML tags and entities using PHP functions, but I have to place the English content back in the HTML tags after translation for proper display. It will also include CSS.

Example:

```
<strong>This is a test</strong><br /> &nbsp; <custom tag>This is a test</custom tag><br />
```

After translation to Spanish I need:

```
<strong>Translated content </strong><br /> &nbsp; <p>Translated content </p><br />
```

How can I preserve the HTML format with out sending HTML to the API?

Comment: i posted my solution in [Prohibit the translation of pieces of text in Google Translate](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/52668)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haha, I also had that problem. But it has been while ago...

I think, there was a problem were - due to translation-nature - some sentenceparts were swaped. So I was not able to fit the tags in at the same position, first. But I think there was a way to get some metadata from the translationprocess, were you can see which part of the sentence have moved to a new position and what the content was... I know, I solved it finally. But I cant recall how :(

If every word takes the same place again after translation, you could first separate all words by whitespace OR htmltag into an array and remember where each HTML-tag was and reapply that after translation...