# Exclude HTML tags when translating with Google Translate API

Tags: javascript, java, html, api, google-translate

Currently I know that `<span class="e;notranslate"e;> </span>` is used to omit out text to translate between the span.

I am looking out for sending content with HTML tag to Translate API and let it return without translating the tags. Is there anyway that tags could be omitted out before translating and putting them back when the JSON returns with the translated text or is there any syntax to exclude Translate API from translating the HTML tags?

Doing some research before I decide to whether code in JS or Java.

Read this before : [Temporary removal of HTML from string for Google Translate API to reduce cost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541908/temporary-remove-html-from-string-for-google-api-translation-to-save-dollars)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Google have a optional parameter `format`.

> •This optional parameter allows you to indicate that the text to be
> translated is either plain-text or HTML. A value of "html" indicates
> HTML and a value of "text" indicates plain-text.
>
> •Default: format=html.

https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/using_rest

Comment: Will this reduce the cost? Google bill translations per character, but it is not clear if this is translated character

Comment: @PlamenVasilev  the cost won't be reduced at all
https://cloud.google.com/translate/pricing#charged-characters

Comment: It clears html tags and returns pure text. How can I maintain html tags?

Comment: The format parameters does nothing for me. No matter whether I set it to "text" or "html", all html tags are removed in the translation.